# Calculating zones in multipart polygon feature using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I was wondering how you can give each zone a value based on how many overlaps there are from a multipart polygon feature. See the picture. If the circles don't overlap I would like the area to have an attribute of, eg P1, and if there are two circles that overlap I would like it to have the attribute P2 and so on...

[image: http://postimage.org/image/dt6pmvtdx/]

Comment: This is [**similar**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51929/how-to-count-and-rasterize-polygon-overlaps-in-arcgis) but may not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you have workstation, you could use [REGIONPOLYCOUNT](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/19313).  Unfortunately this capability never made it into ArcGIS desktop.

If you have VBA installed, you could adapt the code posted [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=84656#249735).

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Count Overlapping Polygons](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1dd4a6832b3d40b494dbf8521cc5134c) tool.  If you want to assign the overlapping values from the buffers to the zonal features (e.g. city block), use [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000).

There is also a good blog from ESRI which describes the methods used in the tool:

[More adventures in overlay: counting overlapping polygons with spaghetti and meatballs](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/13/spaghetti_and_meatballs/)

[image]