# Finding areas which are inside maximum of 2 buffer zones using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

I have a territory with supermarkets. I'd like to find the areas in this territory which has less than 3 supermarket in its vicinity. For that, I created a 1 mile buffer for each POI.

Is there a way to choose the areas in ArcGIS, which are overlayed by maximum 2 buffer zone?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and find out how to write good questions. A good question shares things that you have tried already and that didn't work.

Comment: That said,  why not intersect the buffer zones and calculate the count statistic? You can then select only those intersections with a count of <= 2.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is almost a duplicate of [Counting and rasterizing polygon overlaps in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51929/counting-and-rasterizing-polygon-overlaps-in-arcgis-desktop) and is answered by step 1-2 in the answer to it:

1. [Union](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) the polygons
2. Add centroid coordinates to output, using [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm)
3. [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) using CENTROID_X and CENTROID_Y as Dissolve fields and OBJECT ID field - COUNT and Statistics field

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a dumb question, but that way I will just pick the Markets which has no other market in it's 1 mile vicinity. If I create a new buffer on these points, am I going to get the needed polygons?

This is my task: "you should create a map that identifies areas (at the LSOA resolution if possible) that have less than 2 supermarkets (and convenience stores), in deprived areas (using the Index of Multiple Deprivation), and a low density of bus stops"

Comment: @Rivyan I have edited the answer